# Загрузка из файла в двусвязный список

Tags: c++, c

Помогите, пожалуйста. 
Необходимо заполнить двусвязный список данными, загруженными из файла. 
Есть 2 варианта реализации такой функции. В обоих случаях создается бесконечный двусвязный список с одной и той же записью (программа зацикливается). Ошибки при чтении из файла и выводе на экран нет. Проблема при записи 2-го элемента. При вводе с клавиатуры элемент создаётся корректно, но не при чтении из файла.

```
struct list {
    char name[11];
    char surname[21];
    char numb[13];
    list * prev;
    list * next;
};
list * beg = NULL;
list * end = NULL;
FILE * f;
   void Add(){ //функция для добавления элемента
list *tmp = (list *)malloc(sizeof(list));
if (tmp == NULL) {
    printf("Не удается выделить память\n");
    return;
}
if (beg == NULL) {
    if (Input(tmp) != false) { //Input - функция ввода с клавиатуры
        tmp->next = NULL;
        tmp->prev = NULL;
        beg = end = tmp;
    } else {
        printf("Запись не добавлена\n");
        return;
    }
} else {
    if (Input(tmp) != false) {
        tmp->prev = end;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        end->next = tmp;
        end = tmp;
    } else { 
        printf("Запись не добавлена\n");
        return;
    }
}
printf("Запись добавлена\n");

}

void Output(list *tmp) { //Вывод на экран элемента
    printf("Фамилия: %s",tmp->surname);
    printf("\nИмя: %s",tmp->name);
    printf("\nНомер: %s \n",tmp->numb);
}
void Show() {//Вывод всего списка
    int count = 0;
    for (list* tmp = beg; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        Output(tmp);
        count++;
    }
    if (count == 0)
        printf("Справочник пуст\n");
}
```

1 вариант

```
void Upload(FILE * f) { //загрузка из файла
    list* tmp = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("Не удается выделить память\n");
        return;
    }
    if ((f = fopen("phone.txt", "rt")) == NULL) {
        printf("Не удается открыть файл\n");
        return;
    }
    int ret = 0;
    while (!feof(f)) {
        if (beg == NULL) {
            ret = fscanf(f, "%10s %20s %12s \n", tmp - > surname, tmp - > name, tmp - > numb);
            if (ret != 0) {
                tmp - > next = NULL;
                tmp - > prev = NULL;
                beg = end = tmp;
            } else {
                printf("Запись не добавлена\n");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            ret = fscanf(f, "%10s %20s %12s \n", tmp - > surname, tmp - > name, tmp - > numb);
            if (ret != 0) {
                tmp - > prev = end;
                tmp - > next = NULL;
                end - > next = tmp;
                end = tmp;
            } else {
                printf("Запись не добавлена\n");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf("Загрузка прошла успешно\n");
    Show();
}
```

2 вариант

```
struct list {
    char name[11];
    char surname[21];
    char numb[13];
    list * prev;
    list * next;
};
list * beg = NULL;
list * end = NULL;
FILE * f;
struct record {
    char name[11];
    char surname[21];
    char numb[13];
}
rec[20];
void Read(FILE * f) {//чтение из файла
    if ((f = fopen("phone.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("Не удается открыть файл\n");
        return;
    }
int ret = 0, i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (feof(f))
        break;
    ret = fscanf(f, "%10s %20s %12s \n", rec[i].surname, rec[i].name, rec[i].numb);
    if (ret == 0)
        printf("Не удалось загрузить");
}

fclose(f);

}

void Upload(FILE *f) { //создание списка на основе считанных данных
list *tmp = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));
if (tmp == NULL) {
    printf("Не удается выделить память\n");
    return;
}
Read(f);
int k;
for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    if (!*rec[k].numb)
        break;
    else {
        if (beg == NULL) {
            tmp->next = NULL;
            tmp->prev = NULL;
            beg = end = tmp;
            strcpy(tmp->surname, rec[k].surname);
            strcpy(tmp->name, rec[k].name);
            strcpy(tmp->numb, rec[k].numb);
    } else {
        tmp->prev = end;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        end->next = tmp;
        end = tmp;
        strcpy(tmp->surname, rec[k].surname);
        strcpy(tmp->name, rec[k].name);
        strcpy(tmp->numb, rec[k].numb);
    }
}

}

printf("Загрузка прошла успешно\n");
Show();

}
```

Comment: Ну понятно. А где у вас функция, добавляющая элемент в список?

Comment: Добавление элемента есть и в этой функции. Есть еще отдельная функция для добавления.

Comment: Хм, наверное есть. Проблема в том, что ваш код слишком сложен, так как делает всё одновременно. Разбейте его на маленькие функции, а?

Comment: Во 2-м варианте разбила функцию на две (чтение из файла и создание и заполнение списка). 1-й вариант не могу упростить аналогичным образом, но он и так проще 2-го. Не знаю, как еще упростить.

Comment: Окей, давайте глянем...

Comment: Ой. Тут какой-то ужас. Смотрю второй вариант, функция `Read`: вы открыли файл, затем в цикле 20 раз прочитали структуру из него. И что потом вы делаете с прочитанной структурой? Ответ: ничего, она просто теряется.

Comment: Нужно убрать цикл и читать структуру без него? Или написать while (!feof(f)), как в первом варианте, чтобы считывалось до конца файла? Как сделать, чтобы данные из структуры копировались в двусвязный список, а не терялись?

Comment: И как без цикла обращаться к элементам структуры?

Comment: Ну, убрать цикл у вас наверное не получится. Так что либо встраивайте вставку в список внутрь цикла, либо оформляйте её отдельной функцией, и вызывайте в цикле.

Comment: А вы точно на С++ пишите?

Comment: На Си. Все в одном цикле у меня в 1-м варианте, но там тоже ошибка.

Comment: Надо ``list* tmp = (list*) malloc(sizeof(list));`` внести внутрь цикла, перед ``ret = fscanf(...)``. Сейчас вы выделили память, заполнили элемент, потом прочитали в него же заново, а новых элементов-то не создаете. Аналогично с вариантом 2 - прочитали нормально, а для списка не создаете новых элементов. Еще в вашем вопросе очень сложно разобраться, т.к. кода много, но при этом он все равно не полный и протестировать его нет возможности, прочитайте внимательно [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).